# Log4j, different appenders, same package and an individual class, write to different files?

Tags: java, log4j

I normally associate a package to an appender.  But in this one case, this class is writing a lot of logs I want to filter out to a different appender.  But the class is in the same package as my other classes.

I am trying to do this:

```
log4j.logger.com.app=DEBUG,MainAppender
log4j.logger.com.app.webservice.Web=DEBUG,WSAppender
```

I want the WSAppender to write to one file but I DON'T want the same logs from the MainAppender.   Right now, the logs from WSAppender also appear in MainAppender.

Comment: `log4j.additivity.com.app.werbservice.web=false` should do the job. I can't test it at the moment unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set additivity=false on the child logger.

See example [here](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-additivity-what-and-why/).

```
log4j.additivity.com.app.webservice.Web = false
```

Comment: log4j.logger.com.app.webservice.Web.additivity = false